# Add group to data frame using monotonically increasing numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping

I've got a data frame that looks like this (the real data is much larger and more complicated):

```
df.test = data.frame(
  sample = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b"),
  day = c(0,1,2,0,1,3,0,2),
  value = rnorm(8)
)

  sample day       value
1      a   0 -1.11182146
2      a   1  0.65679637
3      a   2  0.03652325
4      a   0 -0.95351736
5      a   1  0.16094840
6      a   3  0.06829702
7      b   0  0.33705141
8      b   2  0.24579603
```

The data frame is organized by experiments but the experiment ids are missed. The same sample can be used in different experiment, but I know that in a single experiment the days start from 0 and are monotonically increasing.

How can I add the experiment ids that can be a numbers {1, 2, ...}?

So the resulted data frame will be

```
  sample day       value  exp
1      a   0 -1.11182146    1
2      a   1  0.65679637    1
3      a   2  0.03652325    1
4      a   0 -0.95351736    2
5      a   1  0.16094840    2
6      a   3  0.06829702    2
7      b   0  0.33705141    3
8      b   2  0.24579603    3
```

I would appreciate any help, especially with a tidy/dplyr solution.

Comment: I know `cumsum`, but how apply it here? Still thinking.

Comment: Does something like `df.test %>% mutate(exp= 1 + cumsum(day - lag(day, default = 0) < 0))` work for you?

Comment: `cumsum(df.test$day == 0)` i assume - I suspect there's a duplicate out there somewhere, but I'm on lunch.

Comment: @Z.Lin: Looks great, exactly what I need. Thanks! Submit it as an answer pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you can do this with `cumsum`:

```
df.test %>% mutate(exp = cumsum(day == 0))
##   sample day       value exp
## 1      a   0  0.09300394   1
## 2      a   1  0.85322925   1
## 3      a   2 -0.25167313   1
## 4      a   0 -0.14811243   2
## 5      a   1 -1.86789014   2
## 6      a   3  0.45983987   2
## 7      b   0  2.81199150   3
## 8      b   2  0.31951634   3
```

Comment: Wow, even simpler. Thanks

Comment: I like the other solution as well, since the first day in an experiment doesn't need to be 0, just less then the last one.

Comment: @yuk, in that case, do you want it to start at zero? Or still at 1?

Comment: I mean theoretically it's possible that 0 is missed in some experiments, so they can start from another number. I just haven't observed it yet. Didn't want to complicate the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diff` :

```
library(dplyr)
df.test %>% mutate(exp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(day) < 0)))

#  sample day      value exp
#1      a   0 -0.3382010   1
#2      a   1  2.2241041   1
#3      a   2  2.2202612   1
#4      a   0  1.0359635   2
#5      a   1  0.4134727   2
#6      a   3  1.0144439   2
#7      b   0 -0.1292119   3
#8      b   2 -0.1191505   3
```